# How can I add this dynamically constructed URL to a PHP variable?

Tags: php

I have a feeling I'm being very silly, but go easy on me as I'm very new to PHP.

So as part of an application, I'm building, I allow users to generate a URL that can be used to access some of their data from outside the platform. The URL is constructed by the PHP script based on URL parameters in the users browser (fear not, the parameters only allow the passing of integers to prevent abuse).

So to create the URL that will be shared, the script does this:

```
https://example.com/shared.php?function=form&account=<?php echo $userid; ?>&form=<?php echo $myform; ?><?php if (isset($_GET['ref'])) { echo '&ref='.$ref; } ?><?php if (isset($_GET['upload'])) { echo '&upload='.$upload; } ?>&key=<?php echo $key; ?><?php if (isset($_GET['saving'])) { echo '&saving='.$_GET['saving']; } ?><?php if (isset($_GET['expdate'])) { echo '&expdate='.$expdate; } ?><?php if (isset($_GET['enc'])) { echo '&enc='.$enc; } ?>
```

**I know I don't need to keep opening and closing the PHP tag, but it was just easier visually when I was putting everything together.**

Anyway, the above does a good job at spitting out the URL, but if I want to add the final URL to a variable, how can I do it?

Obviously, normally it would be trivial:

```
$whatever = 'https://example.com/shared.php?function=form&account='.$variable.'&something='.$variable2.'etc etc
```

But because I've got if statements that check for URL parameters, I'm not sure how to accomplish it.

Comment: Either use the ternary operator in those places to replace any if / if-else constructs, or do it in multiple steps, by _appending_ stuff to your variable in if statements.

Comment: Please share the `if` block that aims to construct the url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate strings with the `.` operator, you don't need to build the URL at once. However, in this case, it'd be easier to just use the builtin [http_build_query()](https://php.net/http_build_query) function. Populate an array as you validate parameters and feed it to the function when done.

P.S. Don't trust client-side validations. People may not care to enforce them when they type in the browser location bar.

Comment: Okay, I see. So build the URL bit by bit.

Re the parameters, just to clarify - the script itself kills the process of it detects anything other than integers in a URL parameter. Users also have no influence over certain variables that are taken from session values (such as userid), and then the final URL they are provided incorporates a key that is essentially a hashed value of all the parameters, salted with a secret key. So a user can't modify anything manually. On the other end, once they share the URL, the same key system prevents the other person from remodifying the URL parameters.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you. The build query function works well. I have updated my post with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to everyone that made suggestions. In the end I went with the following:

```
$array = array(
    'account' => $userid,
    'form' => $myform,
    'key' => $key,
);

if (isset($_GET['ref'])) {
    $array['ref'] = $ref;
}

if (isset($_GET['upload'])) {
    $array['upload'] = $upload;
}

if (isset($_GET['saving'])) {
    $array['saving'] = $_GET['saving'];
}

if (isset($_GET['expdate'])) {
    $array['expdate'] = $expdate;
}

if (isset($_GET['enc'])) {
    $array['enc'] = $enc;
}

$finalURL = http_build_query($array);
```

Works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

You can always prepare parameters *before* putting into string. Or there is `ternary operator ?:`

```php
$ref = $_GET['ref'] ? '&ref=' . $_GET['ref'] : '';
$upload = $_GET['upload'] ? '&upload=' . $_GET['upload'] : '';
$saving = $_GET['saving'] ? '&saving=' . $_GET['saving'] : '';
$expdate = $_GET['expdate'] ? '&expdate=' . $_GET['expdate'] : '';
$enc = $_GET['enc'] ? '&enc=' . $_GET['enc'] : '';

$whatever = "https://example.com/shared.php?function=form&account={$userid}&form={$myform}{$ref}{$upload}&key={key}{$saving}{$expdate}{$enc}";
```

Or make it dynamic using `http_build_query()`:

```php
$params = [
    'function' => 'form',
    'account' => $userid,
    'form' => $myform,
    'key' => $key,
    'ref' => $_GET['ref'] ?? null,
    'upload' => $_GET['upload'] ?? null,
    ...
];

$url = 'https://example.com/shared.php?';
// array_filter will remove any empty value
$url .= http_build_query(array_filter($params));
```